# Mysql - move from one table to another if row doesnt exist in new table

Tags: mysql

I want to move the row of my table to another table if a column doesnt exist in the new table.
Say i want to move login info, and that i check on email. It would be like this in text form:

Move row from table1 if email doesnt match any email row in table2 (do nothing if it exists already in table2). 
I currently have this code which doesnt check if email exists in the new table but i want to be able to:

```
INSERT INTO logins(firstname, lastname, email, departmentid)
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, departmentid FROM temp_uploads WHERE tempuploadid = ?
```

Do i have to join two table in the select statement? Or could it be done in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the folllowing query:

```
INSERT INTO logins(firstname, lastname, email, departmentid)
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, departmentid 
FROM temp_uploads 
WHERE tempuploadid = ?
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email = temp_uploads.email
);
```